# XML .attributes not working

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml

in an XML node that looks like this:

[image]

why would this code not work?

```
                xml = $.parseXML( xml );
                console.log(xml);
                plot = $(xml).find("movie");
                aP = plot.attributes
                console.log(aP);
```

I am getting undefined for console log. aP

i also tried aP = $(plot).attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attributes` is not a jquery property. Try `plot.get(0).attributes` this way you can use the attributes property on your element and not on a jquery object.

```
$(xml).find("movie"); //returns jquery object
$(plot) // is a jquery object of a jquery object. You really want your object to be a jquery object aye?
```

> get(index): Description: Retrieve one of the elements matched by the
>   jQuery object.

In other words, your get returns an actual element.

Comment: Thanks brotha, you answered a lot in one go